# Border Corner Radius Fill Atrocity

Tags: wpf

I have a border defined like so:

```
<Border x:Name="BaseBar" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Height="29" CornerRadius="0,0,16,16" Grid.Row="2">
<Border.BorderBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF6E6E6E" Offset="0.004"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF1A1A1A" Offset="0.043"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.BorderBrush>
<Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF232323" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>
```

It doesn't fill correctly when the corners have a radius, though.  Here is an image of the bottom left corner:

[image: Border fills poorly at radius corner]

You can clearly see the brighter background shining through the darker foreground.  Is there a way to alleviate this?

EDIT: Additional picture, showing that it is the background shining through:

[image: Border fills poorly at radius corner]

In this case, only the white half of the background is seen, whereas the black half (while also getting through) is not really detectable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I usually nest two Borders inside each other. This only works if the inner fill color will be opaque, but yours already is so this should be fine.

So instead of, for example (using solid colors instead of gradients to make the example easier to follow):

```
<Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" CornerRadius="0,0,16,16"
        BorderBrush="Blue" Background="Gray">
  ...
</Border>
```

you could instead use:

```
<Border CornerRadius="0,0,16,16" Background="Blue">
  <Border CornerRadius="0,0,15,15" Background="Gray" Margin="1,1,1,2">
    ...
  </Border>
</Border>
```

So the outer Border uses the "border" color as its `Background`, and then the inner Border sets its `Margin` to the "border width" and then uses the real "background" color for its `Background`. The effect is the same, but the semi-transparent seam is gone.

To make it look right, you need to tweak the inner border's `CornerRadius` -- it's inside the border, so it's a slightly smaller radius than the outside corner. If the border was 1 pixel wide, then you'd want your `CornerRadius` to be 1 pixel smaller; but since you've got an uneven border, you'll probably just want to eyeball it to see what looks right.

Answer (score 1):

**One more option:** I wrote a subclass of Border that fixes the antialiasing gap. Latest code [here](https://gist.github.com/JVimes/52fbebeac224609ee45073674c2ba4f6). Use however you wish.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the BorderThickness ans BorderBrush you have set.
Try it like this :

```
    <Border x:Name="BaseBar" BorderThickness="0" Height="29" CornerRadius="0,0,16,16">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF232323" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
```

The Border.BorderBrush isint the same as the Border.Background so it seems like you see  the brighter background shining through the darker foreground but i think its just your Border.BorderBrush.

Comment: I require the border for visual effect, so I can't set it to 0.  Also, it isn't just the Border.BorderBrush shining through.  Whatever color is behind the window at any given moment is what shines through (I checked that :) ).

Comment: You where right about the color shining trough! Tough, i think you should try to do your visual effects otherwise. Can you guive more info about the use of your borders?

Comment: Yes?  How otherwise should I do my visual effects?

Comment: I dont know, i asked you to guive more information on your visual effects. But anyway the answer of Joe White seems better than mine.